# Testing Django signals

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to test my Django signals and wrote the following test in `pytest`.

```
@pytest.fixture
def tester():
    return StripeTester()

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_should_send_signal_when_charge_succeeds(client, monkeypatch, tester):
    signal_was_called = False

    def handler(sender, order, charge, **kwargs):
        signal_was_called = True

    charge_succeeded.connect(handler)
    # Charge normally are several lines of code that also include
    # client, monkeypatch, tester. However, that part works as I 
    # receive the signal (see below). That's why I simplified it.
    charge(100)

    assert signal_was_called == True
    charge_succeeded.disconnect(handler)
```

In my signal I added a print statement:

```
@receiver(signal=charge_succeeded)
def create_transaction(sender, **kwargs):
    print("TEST")
```

I can see **TEST** when running `pytest` so the signal seems to go through. However I always get this error message when running `pytest`:

```
assert signal_was_called == True
assert False == True
```

Do you have any idea why it's not True, despite the signal is working?

Comment: afaik handlers are loaded at startup (when django loads) and can't be added dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `signal_was_called` variables are not the same, each are local to their function. Your handler is just declaring a new variable as True, not changing the `signal_was_called` variable from `test_should_send_signal_when_charge_succeeds`.

You could use `global`:

```
def handler(sender, order, charge, **kwargs):
    global signal_was_called
    signal_was_called = True
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't consider the global var